# Paying Debt Off in a year

Tags: finance

I want to know how to calculate **minimum fixed monthly payment** needed in order to pay off a credit card balance within 12 months. I just want to understand the concept, and how to work around this problem. Any book suggestion on this kind of problem will also be helpful.

*Example - 
The outstanding balance on the credit card = 4773
, Annual interest rate = 0.2*

Thanks in advance!

I just want to add that, the annual interest rate is 20% (i.e. 0.2)
My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Where did you get that credit? Or is that $20\%$? Rough estimate: divide balance by $12$ and add half the percentage. This should work well for $0.2\%$, and up to $10\%$, but may be noticeably off for $20\%$. So $ 4773/12\approx 398$, plus $10\%$ is plus $40$, to give a monthly rate of $\approx 438$.

Comment: if you could find a 0.2% interest rate credit card, i'd like to know... @LutzL, you're basically *stealing* money at that point.

Comment: How so? The exact solution is $442,6077$, which is noticeably off, as announced, but still close enough for a first estimate.

Comment: Keep in mind that the answers provided below would be different depending on if you made your first payment immediately, or after 1 month, and whether the interest rate you quoted was nominal or effective

Comment: @Tyler: Ah, okay. But not everyone gets to play primary dealer (of the federal reserve bank).

Answer (score 4):

A series of payments made at fixed points in time are called [annuities.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity_%28finance_theory%29)

Essentially, you are summing up a finite geometric series. If you want to calculate how much you'd have to pay per month to pay off a $ \$ 4773$ debt at an annual effective rate of $20 \%$, we'd first convert our annual effective interest rate to the effective interest rate per month:

$(1 + i) = (1 + i_{12})^{12} \implies i_{12} = (1.2)^{1/12}-1$.

Once we have that, we need to solve

$4773 = P\frac{1 - (1+i_{12})^{-12}}{i_{12}}$.

At this point you can just plug numbers in.

Annuities are really flexible and pretty interesting, so I'd encourage you to read the wikipedia page. Unfortunately, the calculations can become tedious, but many calculators will calculate the values for you.

EDIT: I want to make clear my assumptions: We start paying *next* month, and the annual effective rate of interest is $20\%$

To explain the $i_{12}$ part, here's a picture:

[image]

If we consider the total interest accrued in the year, it's $1 + i$. We want to change this into a monthly interest though, since we are making a payment every month. So, the payment made in the first month will accrue interest from time $1$ until time $12$, the second payment from time $2$ until time $12$, etc. Basically, we want to find $i_{12}$ so that $(1 + i) = (1 + i_{12})^{12}$ for that reason. We could just use $(1 + i)$, but that would introduce fractional exponents.

I should also apologize also. I was using the notation $i^{(12)}$ originally which is actually something called the *nominal* rate of interest, and the relationship is $i_{12} = \frac{1}{12}i^{(12)}$. The notation really isn't as horrible as I make it seem, I promise!

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler for clearly answering the problem. It's really helpful!! I will go ahead and read the Wikipedia page now, any good suggestion for the books on the same. A book that can teach me the concepts from the beginning. 

Can you just explain the idea behind 

(1+i)=(1+i(12))12⟹i(12)=(1.2)1/12−1.

Comment: I learned about it from Kellison's Theory of Interest, and then from a study manual for the actuarial FM exam (the ASM version). Let me know if my elaboration helps.

Comment: I got interested in this financial maths problem, as I was trying to solve one problem using Python. I wanted to learn the concept, and hence came here, instead of going to the computer science/programming forum. As, most of the programming is basic maths.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for breaking down that problem for in that timeline format, I somewhat got the idea. What book would you suggest for a beginner like me in Financial Maths? A basic introductory book that can clearly cover the topics on compound interest, annuities etc. (Should I ask this question in a separate thread?)

Comment: you certainly can. i haven't looked at very many so i can't really compare any of them to each other to say which are the best. I used Stephen Kellison's Theory of Interest in a college course, and used an actuarial study manual to pass my exam. You could probably even use [this](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/actuarieshall/mainf.pdf). I can't vouch for it, but at least it's free!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and that link(I am gonna start reading & practicing from it)

Answer (score 3):

Let $B_1$ be your current balance that you will start paying this month, $B_i$ for month $i$, and $P$ the amount of the fixed payment. You'll pay off your bill in month 12, and want the 13th statement to be 0.

$$ B_1 = B_1$$
$$B_2 = \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)(B_1-P)$$
$$B_3 = \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)\left(\left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)(B_1-P)-P\right) = \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^2B_1 - \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^2P -\left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)P$$

$$B_4  = \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^3B_1 - \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^3P -\left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^2P - \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)P$$

$$\vdots$$

$$B_{13}  = \left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^{12}B_1 - P\sum_{i=1}^{12}\left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^{i}$$

You want $B_{13}=0$ which gives:

$$P = \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^{12}B_1}{\sum_{i=1}^{12}\left(1+\dfrac{0.2}{12}\right)^{i}} = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{61}{60}\right)^{12}\left(\dfrac{1}{60}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{61}{60}\right)^{13}-\dfrac{61}{60}}B_1$$

With $B_1=4773$ your payments rounded to the nearest cent is $\$434.90$

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, or over-complicated it? I don't know.

Comment: Thank you so much David for your taking your time out and solving that for me. I got the concept! :)

Answer (score 2):

So let me add how to get to the estimate formula: As usual, you start paying at the end of the first month, and as in Tylers answer you get
$$
B = P⋅\frac{1 - (1+i^{month})^{-12}}{i^{month}}
$$
however, as in David Peterson's answer, banks compute $i^{month}=i^{annual}/12$. Now cite Sir Isaac Newton for the binomial series
$$
(1+i)^{-12}=1-12i+\frac{12⋅13}2i^2-\frac{12⋅13⋅14}6i^3\pm...
$$
and insert to get
$$
B=P⋅(12-6⋅13⋅i+2⋅13⋅14⋅i^2\mp...)
$$
which when inverted gives
\begin{align}
P&=\frac B{12}(1 + \frac{13}2⋅i^{month} + \frac{143}{12}⋅(i^{month})^2+...)\\
&=\frac B{12}(1 + \frac{13}{12}\frac{i^{annual}}2 + \frac{143}{12^3}⋅(i^{annual})^2+...)
\end{align}
Which results in the rule: Divide balance by 12 and increase that number by one half of the annual interest rate. This will be too low, since $\frac{13}{12}$ is about $8\%$ bigger than $1$. For estimates, make that 10%.

Thus for the given balance, $B/12$ is $398$, 10% of that is 40, increase by 10% to 44, thus the first estimate is 438 and the corrected estimate is 442. The exact payment rate is 442,61.